# Django deployment with mysql database on personal server

Tags: mysql, django, ubuntu, linode

I am working on deploying my Django project on Linode. My MySQL database that I used during development was on a ubuntu server that I have at my house. This was different that the computer I wrote the program on. In the `settings.py` file I had the database connections set up and working.  On my personal server at home I have updated the UFW to allow the new linode ip address and granted privileges to the ip address also. When I go to run the server on deployed project on linode, I get an error (`2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'personal server ip address':3306' (110)"`).

How do I get the linode server to be able to talk to my personal server's MySQL database?

Comment: It could be an easier option just to install MySQL on the Linode server and connect Django to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iiuc, you are trying to connect from linode to your home server - this is an odd configuration and will be problematic

what you need to do is to allow incoming connections at the router level so that packets are not dropped via port forwarding - I think your router is blocking the incoming DB connection

But like Yevhen said - it is a better approach to have MySql in Linode directly

Comment: Thank you both. After a lot more research and reading I found that I would have to set up a dynamic DNS since my home's IP address is not static. To get one would cost a lot of money from my ISP and then a lot of work arounds. I did go with setting up a new instance of mysql on my server and was able to use mysql workbench to ssh into it and basically have the same functionality.